# Horizontal line over multiple ordinary characters to indicate an active-low line

Tags: overline, electronics

I'm trying to typeset something that discusses digital electronics.  To indicate that a signal is active-low, one draws a horizontal line over the name of the signal.  That is, the line goes over ALL of the letters.

I can create this using `\overline{CLK}`, but because this works only in math mode, the `CLK` text is rendered in italic.  I saw elsewhere that `\={C}` can work, but that's only for a single character.  When writing about active-low signals in plain ASCII, the usual thing to do is prepend a slash: `/CLK`.  But since this is LaTeX, I figured that with this most excellent typesetting engine, there's a way to draw a horizontal line across arbitrary strings.  So, what do I do?

Comment: While there are many possible ways, the easiest may be `$\overline{\textrm{CLK}}$`.

Comment: That works, but I'm also trying to get that to work as a new command.
I have \newcommand*{\activelow[1]}{$\overline{\hbox{{#1}}}$} which results in an overlined 0 prepended and the actual signal name is left untouched.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like this does what I want:

`\newcommand\activelow[1]{$\overline{\hbox{{#1}}}$}`